# how can i hide password_persist txt file in esb_home directory?

Tags: passwords, wso2, wso2-esb

I put password_persist.txt file in client site, because esb works as windows server. but we are concern about security of this password. because everyone can have access to that.
They don't want to use password_tmp file every time.
Is there any solution for hiding it or hash it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We run our ESB as a windows service with the Log On As set to a user we setup specifically to run our ESB and other wso2 products (ex. domain\wso2user).  We then use a data security product, in our case Vormetric, to lock that file down so that only that user we have setup to run our windows service has access to that file.  All other users are denied access to viewing that file.

We worked with our security team to arrive at this solution so I would recommend speaking to yours and seeing if they have a solution in place for this type of scenario.  My only experience with this is using Vormetric but I am sure there are countless other products out there that will provide similar functionality.

Joe

Comment: Thank you, I found another tools for this aim that was free. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to take the base64 encoded key-store password, decode it and generate the password-temp file at server startup using the server startup script. In Linux you could include

```
echo d3NvMmNhcmJvbgo= | base64 -d | tee $CARBON_HOME/password-tmp
```

at the start of the 
`elif [ "$CMD" = "start" ]; then` block. You should be able to do something similar for windows as well. It would be better to go with encryption though.

Comment: Thank you. I searched about this script but I couldn't find any thing.

Comment: NP. I was referring to the wso2server.sh script.